# Weka, how to use clustering method to group similar string patterns

Tags: string, attributes, cluster-analysis, weka

I am using clustering methods of Weka to group similar string patterns. I have firstly use the fonction "stringtowordVector" of weka and then I directly used some methodes of clustering, but I can't get correct results, could someone give me some correct methods to group this kind of data? This is a small part of my data :

```
@relation ponds
@ATTRIBUTE LCC string
@data
acegiadfgiacehiacehiacfhjacehjadfhjacfgiadfhjadfhjadfhjacfhjadf
acehiadfhjacehiadfhjadfhjadfhjadfhjacfhfhjacehj
acehiadfhjacehiadfhjadfhjadfhjadfhjacfhjadfhjadfhjadfhjadfhjadfhjacehj
acehiadfhjacehiadfhjadfhjacfhjaacehjadfhjadfhjadfhjacfhj
acehiadfhjacehikkkkkkkkkkk
```

in fact every line of this data represent an extracted frequent pattern(by a data mining algorithm) and each letter a c or e... represent an attribute, but every pattern(every line) doesn't have the same number of attributes, so how could I use the clustering methods to group similar patterns? Thank you very much!!! Looking forward to your response :)

David

Comment: maybe this can be represented with a [Hidden Markov Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model), so if you definitely need to use Weka, maybe check out [HMMWeka](http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02mg/software/hmmweka/index.html), but I have never used it myself (hard for me to get fluent in this)

Answer (score 0):

Every string is different, so "string to word vector" will give them different vectors. Please read "bag of words model" for details.

You could try clustering with Levenshtein distance, but I would rather try designing some *good* features for your problem.